# Trying to create cert for RSA and Not ECDH

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, certificate-authority, rsa

I have an old application that needs the obsolete RSA key and not the ECDH. I know the ECDH is newer. I have tried this

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out private-key.pem
```

I create my csr

I import the csr in CA to create cer and the chain. After doing all this I still get the new version of the ssl cert.

**The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with P-256, and AES_128_GCM**

I want this:

**The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS1.2, RSA, and AES_256_CBC with HMAC-SHA1**

The application servers are Windows.

Comment: The protocols and ciphersuites that you are seeing in the TLS connection to your server (e.g. TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with P-256, and AES_128_GCM) are only loosely connected (at best) to your certificate.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133409/link-between-cipher-suites-and-certificate-key and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90422/ssl-certificates-and-cipher-suites-correspondence for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You got this: TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with P-256, and AES_128_GCM, but you wanted: TLS1.2, RSA, and AES_256_CBC with HMAC-SHA1

There are two different but related things here: the algorithm in your certificate, and the configuration of your TLS server.

So you made yourself an RSA signing certificate, and you configured your TLS to offer cipher suites with ECDHE key exchange and ***RSA signature***. You are looking for a cipher suite that does ***RSA key exchange***, which is probably not going to work with the certificate you created.

I won't do all the work for you, but I'll give some pointers: first, to get a certificate that can work with ***RSA key exchange***you'll need a certificate with `keyUsage = keyEncipherment`. Check the cert you have; I would bet it's `keyUsage = digitalSignature`, in which case you'll need to edit your openssl ca config file to list (see [this article](https://www.aemcorp.com/managedservices/blog/creating-digital-certificates-using-openssl))

```
keyUsage   = critical, keyEncipherment
```

and then you'll need to edit your openssl tls settings to add the RSA key agreement ciphers (see [the openssl man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html)). Good luck!

Comment: I tried your recommendations and it is still defaulting to the higher encryption. We do have a server that has an older cert that is working fine on. I looked at the order of ssl cyphers on the server and its not configured. I also read through the articles you posted and used what they had listed.

Comment: @MarkH Hmm. That's not really a lot of information to work with.

Comment: @MarkH Are you able to post the two certs (working and not working)?